# Javascript Difference Between x=10; if(x) and if(x===10)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I understand that in terms of boolean

`x = true;
if(x) //This is the same as if(x === True)
 doSomething();`

But if one were to set x to a number, then what does the if condition mean?
Does the condition mean if(x === true)? If so, why is that?

Comment: Understand truthy/falsey in JavaScript: inhttp://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: I recomend you read --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: `if (x)` is eqivalent to `if (Boolean(x))`, not matter the value of `x`.

Comment: @Chintan That makes sense now. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript the below are *falsey*

- `false`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `0`
- `""`
- `NaN`

Anything except the above are *truthy*, including numbers, except `0`. So `10` is a truthy value and hence the `if` block, executes.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yup. That one is *falsey* too.

Answer (score 0):

in short is as follows:

```
//!length = if(x.length);
var a;                                      //undefined == if(!a) == !length
var b = "";                                 //void  == if(!b)
var c = " ";                                //blank == if(c) == length
var d = "text";                             //there == if(d) == length
var e = true;                               //true == true == if(e)
var f = false;                              //false == false == if(!f)
var g = null;                               //false == if(!g) == !length
var h = 0;                                  //0 == if(!h)
var i = 1;                                  //true == if(i)
var j = 0/0;                                //NaN == if(!j)
var k = document.body;                      // == if(k)
var l = document.getElementById("nothing"); // if(!l) == !length
```

Javascript is very flexible with regards to checking for "`null`" values. I'm guessing you're actually looking for empty strings, in which case this simpler code will work:

```
if(!blah){
```

Which will check for empty strings (`""`), `null`, `undefined`, `false` and the numbers `0` and `NaN`

```js
var a;           //undefined == if(!a) == !length
var b = "";      //void  == if(!b)
var c = " ";     //blank == if(c) == length
var d = "text";  //there == if(d) == length
var e = true;    //true == true == if(e)
var f = false;   //false == false == if(!f)
var g = null;    //false == if(!g) == !length
var h = 0;       //0 == if(!h)
var i = 1;       //true == if(i)
var j = 0/0;     //NaN == if(!j)
var k = document.body; // == if(k)
var l = document.getElementById("nothing"); // if(!l) == !length

consoletotal(l);

function consoletotal(bb){
    consolea(bb);
    consoleb(bb);
    consolec(bb);
    consoled(bb);
    consolee(bb);
}
function consolea(bb){
    if(bb){
        console.log("yes" + bb);
    }
}
function consoleb(bb){
    if(bb===true){
        console.log("true" + bb);
    }
}
function consolec(bb){
    if(bb===false){
        console.log("false" + bb);
    }
}
function consoled(bb){
    if(!bb){
        console.log("no" + bb);
    }
}
function consolee(bb){
    if(bb.length){
        console.log("length" + bb);
    }
}
```